# Add text view dynamically inside a tab (Android)

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs, textview, addition

I am trying to add a textview inside a tab dynamically. using this code

```
Oncreate()
{  
    OA.loaderShow(this); //Loader display  
    new Thread(new Runnable(){  
        public void run()
        {  
            Looper.prepare();  
            fetchDocs();  
            OA.loaderHide(); //Loader Hide  
            Looper.loop();  
        }  
    }).start();  
}  

fetchDocs()
{  
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);    
    TextView text = new TextView(this);              
    text.setText(mytext);        
    layout.addView(text);  
}
```

I am getting this error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its view".

Please Help.

Comment: please add the all method code.

Comment: Are you trying to add this textview into an xml where you defined your TabHost or its a different xml?And please post some more of your code along with xml you are try to add LinearLayout to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a handler like this:

EDIT:

```
protected static final int SET_TEXTVIEW = 0;
Oncreate()
{  
    OA.loaderShow(this); //Loader display  
    new Thread(new Runnable(){  
        public void run()
        {  
            Looper.prepare();  
            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(SET_TEXTVIEW)); 
            OA.loaderHide(); //Loader Hide  
            Looper.loop();  
        }  
    }).start();  
} 
public Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case SET_TEXTVIEW :
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    TextView text = new TextView(this);
                    text.setText(mytext);
                    layout.addView(text);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can u explain a little more. I dont know how to use this code?

Comment: Ok, you edited your post.. replace your "fetchDocs();" with "handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(SET_TEXTVIEW));"
Add the handler shown above to your class. i will edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Put above inside the following block

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Overridepublic void run() {//your code here}}`

Comment: I am getting this new error "The Specified Child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: use layout.removeAllViews() before adding textview

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the onCreate method rather than adding from else where.

Comment: I am calling this in oncreate method with loader only.